# Run multiple searches from CSV at once in PowerShell to copy items

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to process a good bit of files and the process is taking forever.  The files are all named via guid and there is corresponding CSV files that have a column containing each guid I'm trying to find.  So, I'm getting the column that contains the guids in the CSV file and then letting PowerShell search for the matching guid in the files folder.  Here is what I have so far, would it be possible to run this search in parallel somehow so it is hunting for multiple files at a times instead of one at a time?

```
$CSV = Import-Csv 'D:\CSVs\csv\test.csv'
$files = Get-ChildItem 'X:\'
$destinationPath = "D:\files\"

ForEach ($guid in $CSV) {
    $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $guid.FileGUID } | Copy-Item -Destination $destinationPath
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could speed up the search by indexing all the `$files` in a hashtable:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv 'D:\CSVs\csv\test.csv'
$files = @{}
Get-ChildItem X:\ |ForEach-Object {
    $files[$_.Name] = $_
}
$destinationPath = "D:\files\"

ForEach ($guid in $CSV) {
    if($files.Contains($guid)){
        $files[$guid] |Copy-Item -Destination $destinationPath
    }
}
```